# ruby - empty string as nil to avoid variable caching

Tags: ruby

`"".chomp` returns `""` and the system command returns empty string if *which* doesn't know it. In other words, the code below will cache "" and not check system again.

```
@wkhtmltoimage ||= `which wkhtmltoimage-proxy`.chomp
```

I'd like to

- keep variable caching, not running system command again if found.
- avoid running the system command twice in the code in order to check `.empty?`

if chomp returned *nil on empty string*, it wouldn't be a problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method which your caching line calls, check in there for an empty string and return nil if it is, else return the output.

```
def wkhtml_to_image_command
  output = `which wkhtmltoimage-proxy`.chomp
  output.empty? ? nil : output
end

@wkhtmltoimage ||= wkhtml_to_image_command
```

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative to method caching, this is a more compact one-liner.

```
@wkhtmltoimage ||= (c=`which wkhtmltoimage-proxy`.chomp).empty? ? nil : c
```

Not as readible as caching a method return, I must admit.